# Insertion mark drawn over drag image in Tree-View control

Tags: winapi, controls, treeview

I am implementing a Tree-View control using Win32 API where an insertion mark is displayed during drag operations.

The problem is that the insertion line is drawn *over* the drag image as shown in the screenshot below. (Note the line going over the document icon on the right.)

[image: Note the line going over the document icon on the right.]

What can I do to prevent that from happening?

This is the code handling the WM_LBUTTONUP message:

```
void TreeviewDlg_OnMouseMove(HWND hwndParent, int x, int y, UINT keyFlags) {
    if(TreeViewGlobals::g_fDragging) {
        HWND hwndTV = 
            (HWND)GetWindowLongPtr(hwndParent, GWLP_USERDATA); // Tree-View control handle

        // convert the dialog coordinates to control coordinates
        POINT point;
        point.x = x;
        point.y = y;
        ClientToScreen(hwndParent, &point);
        ScreenToClient(hwndTV, &point);     
        ImageList_DragShowNolock(FALSE); // turn off the dragged image 
                                         // so the background can be refreshed

        // Find out if the pointer is on the item. If it is, put insert mark. 
        TVHITTESTINFO tvht;
        tvht.pt.x = point;
        HTREEITEM htiTarget;  // Handle to target item. 
        if((htiTarget = TreeView_HitTest(hwndTV, &tvht)) != NULL) {
            TreeView_SetInsertMark(hwndTV, htiTarget, TRUE);
        }
        ImageList_DragShowNolock(TRUE);
        ImageList_DragMove(point.x, point.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to put a `UpdateWindow(hwndTV);` after `TreeView_SetInsertMark(...)`.

Comment: Have you tried setting the 'Explorer' Window Theme (`SetWindowTheme`)?

Comment: @zett42 : It is always simple once you know how. Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia : I tried using themes for another reason but I keep getting the following link error: `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__SetWindowTheme@12 referenced in function "int __cdecl TreeviewDlg_OnInitDialog(struct HWND__ *,struct HWND__ *,long)" (?TreeviewDlg_OnInitDialog@@YAHPAUHWND__@@0J@Z)`